# Share process memory with mmap

Tags: c, linux, ipc, mmap

I have a C program that generates large amounts of data in memory, and I need to share one particular section of this data in memory, so that another process can have read access to it.

I'm attempting to use `mmap` to do this, but I'm not having much success.  Here is my code:

```
//Code above generates a pointer to the memory section I need to share, named addr

if (infoBlock->memory_size == 1073741824) { //This is the data block I need to share
   int err, fd;
   fd = open("/tmp/testOutput", (0_RDWR | 0_CREAT), S_IWUSR);
   if (fd < 0) {
         perror("Couldn't create output file\n");
         goto failedExit;
    }

    unsigned *p = mmap(addr, 1073741824, PROT_READ, (MAP_SHARED | MAP_FIXED), fd, 0);
    if (!p) {perror("mmap failed"); goto failedExit; }
    printf("p is now: %p\n", p); //This should point to the shared mapping
    printf("%u\n", *p); //Try to print out some data from the mapping

}
```

After running the program, I can see the file /tmp/testOutput is there, but it's size is 0.  I'm not sure if that's a normal thing with memory mappings, as it's not technically a file.  Also all of the output within my program points to the same memory address.

I can also see the memory map present within the /proc/PID/maps, with a reference to /tmp/testOutput.

Everything seems to run, however when it comes to dereferencing the pointer, the program exits, I'm assuming this is because I've done the mapping wrong, and the pointer is pointing to something it shouldn't be.

If anyone can spot what I'm doing wrong, or can offer some advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you consider that this is some big-ass amount of memory you are trying to allocate??? Maybe this is giving your prog a hard time.

Comment: The file you are trying to map is 0-sized, so `mmap()` will fail trying to map anything more than 0 bytes from that file. Try extending the size of the file to cover the mapping first. Also note, that if `mmap()` were to succeed, it would effectively replace the entire contents of `[addr, addr+1073741824)` with the contents of the file - not the other way around. It appears you're trying to map an existing block of memory onto a new file. That's not the way it works...

Comment: Thanks twalberg, how would you suggest doing that?  Could I use fseek to set the size of it?

Comment: There are a number of ways to extend the size of a file - `fseek()` followed by an `fwrite()` would be one. `ftruncate()` would be another, if your library contains it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've mapped the storage associated with that file (or tried to) into your process, and you've insisted that it be mapped at an address you're already using for something else (presumably, `addr` was allocated somehow).

You don't say whether `p` actually does have the address you requested, and as suspectus points out, your error checking is broken.

### Your Confusion:

You can't associate arbitrary heap or other process memory pages with a file after the fact. You have to allocate them in the filesystem, and then map them. (There is a way to associate them with a UNIX pipe using vmsplice, although it isn't exactly what you asked for).

Note the `MMAP_FIXED` flag will just *replace* the page which was occupied by your data, with the new pages associated with the file. Without that flag, the address hint would be ignored and the mapping placed elsewhere.

### The Solution:

1. [ftruncate](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) the file to your desired size *before* mapping it (this allocates storage in the filesystem)
2. map it and *then* populate it
3. fix your `mmap` error checking

If you can't change your allocation scheme, the best you can manage is to *copy* your process-local memory into the mapping, in which case you might as well just `write` it to the file.

The ideal case would look something like this:

```
void *alloc_mmap(const char *filename, size_t length)
{
    int fd;
    fd = open(filename, (0_RDWR | 0_CREAT), S_IWUSR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't create output file\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (ftruncate(fd, length)) {
        perror("Couldn't grow output file\n");
        close(fd);
        return NULL;
    }

    void *p = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (p == -1) {
        perror("mmap failed");
        close(fd);
        return NULL;
    }
    close(fd);
    return p;
}

// now you've allocated your memory, you can populate it and it will be
// reflected in the file
```

Comment: Thanks Useless.

After truncating the file to the correct size in the file system first, then mmap'ing, the data is in there.  I'll now work on better error checking/handling.  

Thanks for you quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extract from the mmap man page.

```
   On  success,  mmap() returns a pointer to the mapped area.  On error, the value
   MAP_FAILED (that is, (void *) -1) is returned, and errno is set  appropriately.
   On  success,  munmap()  returns 0, on failure -1, and errno is set (probably to
   EINVAL).
```

The test for success should be changed to test for -1 return value of mmap. Then check the errno 
value. HTH.